# Ajax posting but object error

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am faccing posting issue. When I increase the total value with button then value are showing but when I click the request button then all posting are updated but balance do not update. And I check the database there insert into "You have transfer $[object Object] Account Balance". Please help what is the problem and help me for perfection.

```js
$(function(){
 
var theTotal = 10;

$('.add').click(function(){
   theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));
});

$('.sub1').click(function(){
 if(theTotal > 10) {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
 };
    $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));
});

$('.sub2').click(function(){
 if(theTotal > 10) {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
 };
    $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));
});

$('.sub3').click(function(){
 if(theTotal > 10) {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
 };
    $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));
});


var af = $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));

 
 $('#request').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/?add=fund',
   data:'qun='+af,
   cache:false,
   beforeSend:function(){
    $('html *').addClass('op-progress');
   }, success:function(html){
    $('html *').removeClass('op-progress');
    document.location.href=_url+'/?add=fund';
   }
  });
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="margin-bottom:15px;">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <button class="sub3 p_btn" value="10"><<<</button>
            <button class="sub2 p_btn" value="10"><<</button>
   <button class="sub1 p_btn" value="10"><</button>
  </td>
      
  <td>
   <span class="f_mb_dol">$</span>
   <span class="total f_mb_text"></span>
   <div class="f_mb_dol">usd</div>
  </td>
      
  <td>
   <button class="add p_btn" value="10">></button>
            <button class="add p_btn" value="10">>></button>
   <button class="add p_btn" value="10">>>></button>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
    
<table>
   <tr>
   <td><button id="request" class="btn_enable" style="cursor:pointer;"><span>Transfer balance</span></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where is the php & mysql code ?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the whole element in the data.
I beleive you need to send the data only. What you are doing in line **var af = $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));** is you are setting the value for that element and assigning the element to a variable.

Remember **.text(something)** sets the value

**.text()** gets the value

```js
$(function(){
var af;
var theTotal = 10;

$('.add').click(function(){
    theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));
});

$('.sub1').click(function(){
 if(theTotal > 10) {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
 }
    $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));
});

$('.sub2').click(function(){
 if(theTotal > 10) {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
 }
    $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));
});

$('.sub3').click(function(){
 if(theTotal > 10) {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
 }
    $('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));
});


$('.total').text(theTotal.toFixed(2));
     $('#request').click(function(){
af = $('.total').text(); 
    console.log(af);
  $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/?add=fund',
   data:'qun='+af,
   cache:false,
   beforeSend:function(){
    $('html *').addClass('op-progress');
   }, success:function(html){
    $('html *').removeClass('op-progress');
    document.location.href=_url+'/?add=fund';
   }
  });
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="margin-bottom:15px;">
 <tr>
   <td>
   <button class="sub3 p_btn" value="10"><<<</button>
            <button class="sub2 p_btn" value="10"><<</button>
   <button class="sub1 p_btn" value="10"><</button>
  </td>
      
  <td>
   <span class="f_mb_dol">$</span>
   <span class="total f_mb_text"></span>
   <div class="f_mb_dol">usd</div>
  </td>
      
  <td>
   <button class="add p_btn" value="10">></button>
            <button class="add p_btn" value="10">>></button>
   <button class="add p_btn" value="10">>>></button>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
    
<table>
    <tr>
     <td><button id="request" class="btn_enable" style="cursor:pointer;"><span>Transfer balance</span></button></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: It might be nice if you indicated in some way _what you have actually changed_

Comment: Do not solve the issue. increase and decrease value not set the .text(), So how can i add the value.

Comment: You have to assign the **af = $('.total').text();** inside the **request** button click. Check the updated answer.